# System.Net.IPAddress returning weird addresses

Tags: vb.net, networking, ip-address, system.net

I am writing a (rather simple :) networking application, and am testing it using `localhost:27488` (`127.0.0.1:27488`).
I am using a `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` for the connection, which takes a `System.Net.IPAddress` to specify the host... the only thing is, I can't figure out how to initialize the class with the right IP address. I went over the MSDN docs and it says it takes either a `Byte(4)` or an `Int64` (`long`) for the address.
The probelm is, when I initialize the `IPAddress` like this:

```
Dim ipAddr As New System.Net.IPAddress(127001)
```

it returns the address as `25.240.1.0`. From what I understand from the docs, `127001` should return `127.0.0.1`... Maybe I missed something there? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13180abx.aspx

Comment: Using your assumption, what if you would have wanted the IP of `12.70.0.1`;  wouldn't that too have been `127001`?  Seems like you did indeed miss something from the docs, like the "_For example, the value 0x2414188f in big-endian format would be the IP address "143.24.20.36"._" part.

Comment: good point... I guess I didn't get that :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: use TcpClient.Connect( String, Int ) instead; it accepts an IPv4/IPv6 address or hostname/alias, so you are not limited to connecting by IP.  e.g.:

```
Dim client As TcpClient
client.Connect( "localhost", 27488 )
client.Connect( "127.0.0.1", 27488 )
```

But where did 25.240.1.0 come from?  Try the following:

- Open Calc, switch to Programmer view, select Dec
- Type in `127001`, then switch to Hex
- Write out the result, adding zeroes on the left to pad to 4 bytes/32 bits: `0001F019`
- Separate that number into individual bytes: `00 01 F0 19`
- Reverse the byte order: `19 F0 01 00`
- Convert each byte back to decimal: `25 240 1 0`
- With dots: `25.240.1.0`

Why reverse the bytes?  Your processor architecture is little-endian; numbers are represented in memory with the least significant byte first.  IPv4 addresses are standardized to big-endian format (most significant byte first; a.k.a. network order).  The `IPAddress( Int64 )` constructor is reversing the bytes to convert from LE to BE.

Reversing the steps above, the correct value for loopback in the `IPAddress( Int64 )` constructor would be `&H0100007F` (hex) or `16777343` (decimal).

The `IPAddress( Byte[4] )` constructor takes the byte array in network order, so that would be `New Byte() { 127, 0, 0, 1 }`

Answer (score 5):

You are misunderstating how it works. Ip address consists of 4 bytes, representing them as `127.0.0.1` is just a human readable convention. Under the hood, 127.0.0.1 is represented as `((127 << 24) | (0 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 1)`.
In your case, it would be much easier and more readable to just use `.Parse(string)` method like this:

`IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");`

Answer (score 2):

Why not try the [IPAddress.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx) method?

You'd do something like:

```
Dim ipAddr as IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")
```