# Powershell - Checking IP Address range based on CSV file

Tags: powershell

I have been developing VM provision script. My question is : I have here-string like below. now , I want to add `route` based on ip address range. I am using CSV file with `BACKUPIP` column.

if an BACKUPIP is in range `10.10.104.1` to `10.10.107.254` it will work `route add xx.xx.xx.xx mask 255.255.255.0 xx.xx.xx.xx -p`

if an BACKUPIP is in range `10.10.180.1` to `10.10.185.254` it will work `route add yy.yy.yy.yy mask 255.255.255.0 yy.yy.yy.yy -p`

Here is my script:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\vm.csv -UseCulture -PipelineVariable row |

ForEach-Object -Process {


    # Create the VM, store result in $vm


    if($($row.IP) -eq '???'){
            route add xx.xx.xx.xx mask 255.255.255.0 xx.xx.xx.xx -p
            }
    else{
            
            route add yy.yy.yy.yy mask 255.255.255.0 yy.yy.yy.yy -p
            
            }


}
```

LAST UPDATE :

```
$rangeFrom104 = '10.10.104.1'
$rangeTo107 = '10.10.107.254'

$rangeFrom180 = '10.10.180.1'
$rangeTo185 = '10.10.185.254'

     

if (([version]$rangeFrom104) -lt ([version]$($row.IP)) -and ([version]$($row.IP)) -lt ([version]$rangeTo107) )
{

route add xx.xx.xx.xx mask 255.255.255.0 xx.xx.xx.xx -p

}

elseif (([version]$rangeFrom180) -lt ([version]$($row.IP)) -and ([version]$($row.IP)) -lt ([version]$rangeTo185) )
{

route add yy.yy.yy.yy mask 255.255.255.0 yy.yy.yy.yy -p

}
```

Comment: What is the question or an error are you getting?

Comment: use the `[version]` type accelerator. [*grin*] yes, really! this works ... >>> `[version]'172.25.104.1' -le [version]'172.25.106.99' -ge [version]'172.25.107.254'` <<< and gives `$True` as the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really like the `[Version]` approach [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) suggested.

Here's another approach that converts the IP addresses to their numeric values:

```
function Convert-IPv4ToDecimal ([string]$IpAddress){
    # helper function to return the numeric value (uint32) of a dotted IP
    # address string used for testing if an IP address is in range.
    $n = [uint32[]]$IpAddress.Split('.')
    # or use: $n = [uint32[]]([IpAddress]$IpAddress).GetAddressBytes()

    # to get the obsolete property ([IpAddress]$IpAddress).Address
    # you need to do the math in reversed order.
    # return [uint32] ($n[3] -shl 24) + ($n[2] -shl 16) + ($n[1] -shl 8) + $n[0]

    # for comparing different ranges as in this question, do not reverse the byte order
    return [uint32] ($n[0] -shl 24) + ($n[1] -shl 16) + ($n[2] -shl 8) + $n[3]
}



$startRange1 = Convert-IPv4ToDecimal '172.25.104.1'
$endRange1   = Convert-IPv4ToDecimal '172.25.107.254'

$startRange2 = Convert-IPv4ToDecimal '172.25.112.1'
$endRange2   = Convert-IPv4ToDecimal '172.25.115.254'

Import-Csv -Path .\vm.csv -UseCulture | ForEach-Object {
    # Create the VM, store result in $vm

    # convert the .BACKUPIP to numeric value
    $backupIp = Convert-IPv4ToDecimal $_.BACKUPIP
    # test the IP range
    if ($backupIp -ge $startRange1 -and $backupIp -le $endRange1) {
        Write-Host "BACKUPIP '$($_.BACKUPIP)' is in Range 1"
        route add xx.xx.xx.xx mask 255.255.255.0 xx.xx.xx.xx -p
    }
    elseif ($backupIp -ge $startRange2 -and $backupIp -le $endRange2) {
        Write-Host "BACKUPIP '$($_.BACKUPIP)' is in Range 2"
        route add yy.yy.yy.yy mask 255.255.255.0 yy.yy.yy.yy -p
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "No range defined for IP address '$($_.BACKUPIP)'"
    }
}
```

Comment: :) At the sametime with you , I have updated my script. compared to your script my script was amateur.

Comment: @Arbelac Nice! I see you have adopted the [version] idea. Never thought of that myself. Pity Lee_Dailey didn't post that as answer, I would have upvoted it for sure.

Comment: compared to your script my script was amateur. :)

Comment: @Arbelac Not amateur at all. I'm keeping this as alternative.

Comment: @Theo - you can get the decimal value of the ip address with this >>> `([ipaddress]'172.25.104.1').Address` <<< that gives the same `23599532` that your function gives.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey yes. But that is marked  [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.address)..

Comment: @Theo - arg! i can't figure out what they want to use instead ... thanks for the info, tho! [*grin*]

Comment: @Theo Hi again ,  btw let's say ,  `BACKUPIP`  equal `172.25.113.23`. it still works  if statement inside elseif statement

Comment: @Arbelac Yes, you're right. I have edited the code, changed the math somewhat and added a bit more explanation.

Comment: `+1` for the use of the [bitwise `-shl` (shift-left) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-7#bitwise-operators).

Comment: Hi Theo , have you had a chance take a look this problem ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63353142/powershell-json-format-to-pac-file-convert

Comment: @Arbelac Just [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63358700/9898643) it ;)

Answer (score 0):

There exists a [`IPAddress` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress?view=netcore-3.1) in .Net:

```
$MyIPAddress  = [System.Net.IPAddress]'10.10.105.7'
$rangeFrom104 = [System.Net.IPAddress]'10.10.104.1'
$rangeTo107   = [System.Net.IPAddress]'10.10.107.254'

If ($rangeFrom104.Address -lt $MyIPAddress.Address -and $MyIPAddress.Address -lt $rangeTo107.Address) {
    # route add xx.xx.xx.xx mask 255.255.255.0 xx.xx.xx.xx -p
}
```

As @Theo commented, the [`Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.address?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_IPAddress_Address) property is obsolete:

> *This property has been deprecated. It is address family dependent.*
> *Please use IPAddress.Equals method to perform comparisons.*

<sub>I guess this is due to compliance with IPv6 (but I presume that the property won't easily cease to exist as that would probably break some legacy programs). Anyways, that doesn't mean that the whole `[System.Net.IPAddress]` class is deprecated. Meaning that you might also use the `GetAddressBytes` method which I think better than a custom function or relying on a (***smart!*** `[version]`) type but also are both limited to IPv4 (~4 bytes).</sub>

With using the `GetAddressBytes` method, you might simple convert the bytes to a [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) string, which format is comparable (e.g. `'10' -gt '0A'`) as long as the byte arrays are of the same size (e.g. both IPv4):

```
function Convert-IPAddressToHexadecimal ([Net.IPAddress]$IPAddress, [Switch]$IPv6) {
    If ($IPv6) {$IPAddress = $IPAddress.MapToIPv6()}
    [BitConverter]::ToString($IPAddress.GetAddressBytes())
}; Set-Alias IP2Hex Convert-IPAddressToHexadecimal

$MyIPAddress  = IP2Hex '10.10.105.7'   # 0A-0A-69-07
$rangeFrom104 = IP2Hex '10.10.104.1'   # 0A-0A-68-01
$rangeTo107   = IP2Hex '10.10.107.254' # 0A-0A-6B-FE

If ($rangeFrom104 -lt $MyIPAddress -and $MyIPAddress -lt $rangeTo107) {
    # route add xx.xx.xx.xx mask 255.255.255.0 xx.xx.xx.xx -p
}
```

If you *do* need to make your script [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) compliant and comparing IP addresses to both IPv4 ranges and IPv6 ranges, you might consider to map *all* IP addresses to an IPv6 address: using: `$MyIPAddress.MapToIPv6().GetAddressBytes()` (the `-IPv6` switch):

```
IP2Hex -IPv6 '10.10.105.7' # 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-FF-FF-0A-0A-69-07
```

---

Update 2020-09-06:
It is unclear whether the [`Address`](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.address?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_IPAddress_Address) property is really obsolete. See: [Avoid byte[] allocations once IPAddress.Address is back #18966](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/18966).
Anyhow, there is a pitfall in using the `Address` property for comparison as it appears that the address is stored as [**Big-Endian**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) read from memory as **Little-Endian** format, see: [System.Net.IPAddress returning weird addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6929487/1701026), causing the last byte in `10.10.104.1` (`1`) to become most significant.
This means that comparing the `Address` property might give an incorrect result if there are differences between multiple bytes in the concerned IP Addressed:

```
([IPAddress]'0.0.0.1').Address -lt ([IPAddress]'0.0.1.0').Address
False
```

Comment: Unfortunatelyyes that is marked  [obsolete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.address), although still works.

Comment: @Theo, you are right. I guess this is due to compliancy with IPv6 (which is not in scope here) but you might of cause also use the [`GetAddressBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes) method which I think still better than a homemade function (which likely has the same limitation) or relying on a (`[version]`) type that is not designed for it.

Comment: @iRon Hi,  I have a script. But , I want to improve a little. can you help me?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150840/extracting-specific-lines-and-export-to-the-another-txt-file