# Powershell - JSON format to PAC file convert

Tags: json, powershell, office365, pac

I have used the following code to display JSON results but now need to change the script to display the output    instead of side by side.  I have tried a script like below, but just cant seem to get it to do what I want.

My question is :

- I want to remove `||` before the last bracket. `if (shExpMatch(host, "*.lync.com") || shExpMatch(host, "*.teams.microsoft.com") || shExpMatch(host, "teams.microsoft.com") || )`  As a result , it will be  `if (shExpMatch(host, "*.lync.com") || shExpMatch(host, "*.teams.microsoft.com") || shExpMatch(host, "teams.microsoft.com"))`
- I need to change the script to display the my desired output instead of side by side.

Here is my script :

```
    $result = Invoke-WebRequest "https://endpoints.office.com/endpoints/worldwide?noipv6&ClientRequestId=b10c5ed1-bad1-445f-b386-b919946339a7"
    $services = ConvertFrom-Json $result
    $likeFilter = "12"
    $services = $services | Where-Object { $_.id -like $likeFilter } 
    $urls = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    
    $services
    
    
    
    
    function add_url($url){
    if(!$urls.Contains($url)){ $urls.Add($url); }
    }
    
    
    
    foreach($service in $services){
    
    foreach($url in $service.urls){ add_url($url);
    }
    }
    
    # OUTPUT
$txt_proxypacText += "// This PAC file will provide proxy config to Microsoft 365 services`r`n"
$txt_proxypacText += "//  using data from the public web service for all endpoints`r`n"
$txt_proxypacText += "function FindProxyForURL(url, host)`r`n"
$txt_proxypacText += "{`r`n"

$txt_proxypacText += "var direct = ""DIRECT"";`r`n"
$txt_proxypacText += "var proxyServer = ""PROXY 10.11.12.13:8080"";`r`n"
$txt_proxypacText += "host = host.toLowerCase();`r`n"
$txt_proxypacText += "if ("

foreach($url in $urls){
$txt_proxypacText += "shExpMatch(host, ""$url"") || "
}



$txt_proxypacText += ")`r`n"
$txt_proxypacText += "{`r`n"
$txt_proxypacText += "`r`n return direct;"
$txt_proxypacText += "`r`n}"
$txt_proxypacText += "`r`n return proxyServer;"
$txt_proxypacText += "`r`n}"
```

Output:

```
// This PAC file will provide proxy config to Microsoft 365 services
//  using data from the public web service for all endpoints
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
var direct = "DIRECT";
var proxyServer = "PROXY 10.11.12.13:8080";
host = host.toLowerCase();
if (shExpMatch(host, "*.lync.com") || shExpMatch(host, "*.teams.microsoft.com") || shExpMatch(host, "teams.microsoft.com") || )
{

 return direct;
}
 return proxyServer;
}
```

My Desired Output :

```
// This PAC file will provide proxy config to Microsoft 365 services
//  using data from the public web service for all endpoints
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    var direct = "DIRECT";
    var proxyServer = "PROXY 10.11.12.13:8080";

    host = host.toLowerCase();

    if(shExpMatch(host, "*.lync.com")
        || shExpMatch(host, "*.teams.microsoft.com")
        || shExpMatch(host, "teams.microsoft.com"))
    {
        return direct;
    }

    return proxyServer;
}
```

Comment: shExpMatch(host, "teams.microsoft.com") - Why you use shExpMatch here ? Just use host == "teams.microsoft.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make use of a Here-String with a preformated set of `shExpMatch(..)` lines.
Using that also relieves you from doubling quotes and string concatenations using `+=`

```
# demo urls
$urls = "*.lync.com", "*.teams.microsoft.com", "teams.microsoft.com"


$hostMatches = $(for ($i = 0; $i -lt $urls.Count; $i++) {
    $prefix = if ($i -eq 0) { '' } else { '        || '}
    '{0}shExpMatch(host, "{1}")'-f $prefix,  $urls[$i]
}) -join [Environment]::NewLine


$txt_proxypacText = @"
// This PAC file will provide proxy config to Microsoft 365 services
//  using data from the public web service for all endpoints
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    var direct = "DIRECT";
    var proxyServer = "PROXY 10.11.12.13:8080";
    host = host.toLowerCase();
    if ($hostMatches)
    {
        return direct;
    }

    return proxyServer;
}
"@

$txt_proxypacText
```

Output:

```
// This PAC file will provide proxy config to Microsoft 365 services
//  using data from the public web service for all endpoints
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{
    var direct = "DIRECT";
    var proxyServer = "PROXY 10.11.12.13:8080";
    host = host.toLowerCase();
    if (shExpMatch(host, "*.lync.com")
        || shExpMatch(host, "*.teams.microsoft.com")
        || shExpMatch(host, "teams.microsoft.com"))
    {
        return direct;
    }

    return proxyServer;
}
```

---

As requested, I think the top part of the code, where you are gathering the urls in an arraylist can be done much easier.

One note before: You are using a `$likeFilter` variable with a string `"12"`.
In that case, you could probably better use the `-eq` operator instead of the `-like` operator that has more use for filtering with wildcards (i.e. `"12*"`).

For now, I'm assuming you want to get only the service with id matching `"12"` exactly.

```
$url    = "https://endpoints.office.com/endpoints/worldwide?noipv6&ClientRequestId=b10c5ed1-bad1-445f-b386-b919946339a7"
$filter = 12

# get an array of urls from the service(s) that get through the filter
$urls = ((Invoke-WebRequest $url | ConvertFrom-Json) | Where-Object { $_.id -eq $filter }).urls | Select-Object -Unique
```

Comment: thanks Theo , I have a question.  I don't want to use these lines `    function add_url($url){
    if(!$urls.Contains($url)){ $urls.Add($url); }
    }
    
    
    
    foreach($service in $services){
    
    foreach($url in $service.urls){ add_url($url);
    }
    }`      Is there any alternative script ? What do you recommended?

Comment: @Arbelac Please see the edited answer. With this, you don't have to fiddle around with an ArrayList nor do you need a helper function. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
# EXAMPLE prepare begin
$urls = @(
    'microsoft.com',
    '*.microsoft.com',
    'teams.microsoft.com',
    '*.teams.microsoft.com')
# EXAMPLE prepare End

$urlLines = $urls | 
ForEach-Object { return $_.Trim() } |
ForEach-Object { 
    if($_.StartsWith('*.')) {
        return "shExpMatch(host, '$($_)')"
    } else { 
        return "host == '$($_)'" 
    }}
         
$innerIf = [String]::Join("`r`n" + (' ' * 8) + "|| ", $urlLines)

#// $txt_proxypacText += "    if ($($innerIf))"
Write-Host "    if ($($innerIf))"

# Output:
# if (host == "microsoft.com"
#    || shExpMatch(host, "*.microsoft.com")
#    || host == "teams.microsoft.com"
#    || shExpMatch(host, "*.teams.microsoft.com"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this - simple counter method:

```
$counter = 0
foreach($url in $urls){
    If ($counter -eq $urls.Count){
        $txt_proxypacText += "shExpMatch(host, ""$url"") `r`n"
    }else{
        $txt_proxypacText += "shExpMatch(host, ""$url"") || `r`n"
    }
    $counter++
}
```

Probably needs some tidying up with the tab characters.